# Play wav file in callback mode [Pyaudio / Python]

Tags: python, audio, callback, pyaudio, synthesis

I wanna play wav file using PyAudio with callback mode. I could play wav file once but then stops. For example, if I want to play a wav file (trumpet sound, etc.) every five seconds, how should I implement this? Also, lemme know how to play array (wav data) in callback mode, just in case.

The code that I've implemented so far in the following...

```
    import pyaudio
    import numpy as np
    import wave
    import time
    
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNEL = 2
    CHUNK = 1024
    RATE = 44100
    
    flag = True
    cur_dt = 0
    
    # reading wav file here
    wf = wave.open('test_3.wav', 'rb')
    
    # instantiate PyAudio (1)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    
    # define callback (2)
    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    
        global flag, cur_dt, wf
    
        if flag:
            wf = wave.open('test_3.wav', 'rb')
            flag = False
    
        data = np.zeros((frame_count,), dtype=np.int16)
        data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    
        # convert bytes to int
        data_int = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)\
    
        # convert int to float
        data_float = data_int.astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
    
        # # convert float to int 
        # data_int_again = (data_float*32768.0).astype(np.int16, order='C')
    
        # ur processing...
        f1 = np.fft.fft(data_float)
        f2 = np.fft.ifft(f1)
        f3 = (f2*32768.0).astype(np.int16)
    
        # make it sound!
        data = f3
    
        # cur_dt += 1
        # print(cur_dt)
    
        return (data.tobytes(), pyaudio.paContinue)
    
    
    # open stream using callback (3)
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True,
                    stream_callback=callback)
    
    # print(p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth())) # paInt16
    # print(wf.getsampwidth()) # 3
    # print(wf.getnchannels()) # 2
    # print(wf.getframerate()) # 44100
    
    stream.start_stream()
    
    # wait for stream to finish (5)
    while stream.is_active():
        time.sleep(5)
        flag = True
    
    # stop stream (6)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    wf.close()
    
    # close PyAudio (7)
    p.terminate()
```